# Long getting treated as 32 bits in Java?

Tags: java, long-integer, bit-shift, bitset

I am trying to run the following code,

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long x = 1 << 39;
        long l = 537150415L;
        l = l | x;

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

This outputs,

```
128
537150415
```

I was expecting `x` to be a large number. `128` looks like `2^7`, which is `2^(39-32)`. But I thought long is 64 bits.

I am trying to make a bitset of numbers present in set. The numbers can be between 1-60.

[JDoodle link](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler#&togetherjs=uH49U5c4Ej) - `[https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler#&togetherjs=uH49U5c4Ej]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `1 << 39` is a 32 bit expression.  So

```
long x = 1 << 39;
```

first calculates a 32 bit value, then sign extends that to a 64 bit value for the assignment.

If you want to create a 64 bit mask, use `1L << 39`.

Comment: Oh,  figured this out just before this answer. Was about to delete the question. :P But will let it be there now. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `1L` instead of `1` to represent 1 as a literal `long`:

```
long x = 1L << 39;
long l = 537150415L;
l = l | x;

System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(l);
```

### Demo

Answer (score -1):

The problem with java is, that `int` is what would be `int32_t` in c++ and `long` is `int64_t`, there are no unsigned types.

That means you have to take the two's complement into consideration, so when the upper bit is set, you have -2^64.

If you only care for a bitset, you shouldn't print the long's directly however. Do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
 System.out.println((l & (1 << i)) != 0 ? "Bit " + i + " is set" : "Bit " + i + " is not set");
}
```

Edit: Okay, while it's not the problem here, I'll leave the answer for the sake of completeness (because those indeed are pitfalls to consider)